# How to pass file or directory path as a REST API parameter to Fastify endpoint

Tags: parameters, path, get, fastify

Actually the question is in the header. A REST endpoint definition is below:

```js
fastify.get('/dir/:path', async (request, reply) => {
  let res = await remote.getDir(request.params.path);
  return { res: res };
});
```

And a call is like

> http://127.0.0.1:3000/dir//

The problem is that Fastify treats the path parameter as continuation of the URL, and says: `"Route GET:/dir// not found"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash `/` is evaluated as a path segment as [written in the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.2.3)

To archive your goal you need to:

1. define the `path` as a query parameter
2. or define the path parameter but encode it in a format that doesn't use `/`, like the base64

Example 1:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')()

fastify.get('/dir', {
  schema: {
    querystring: {
      type: 'object',
      required: ['path'],
      properties: {
        path: { type: 'string' }
      }
    }
  }
},

async function (request, reply) {
  return request.query
})

fastify.listen(8080)

// call it with: http://localhost:8080/dir?path=/
```

Comment: Could you please specify exactly what do you mean by 'define as query parameter'? I tried to use `...?path=:path`